# Common Log format bytes - access log : Clarification

Tags: logging

I thought I knew this, but am confused :( Need some clarification on it -

In the CLF format (access log for httpd, tomcat, jboss, weblogic etc etc), what does the "bytes" field indicate ? Is it the bytes transferred from the server to the client or client to the server ? I believe its the former ; but in that case what happens when the POST method is invoked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the bytes sent in the response, even if it's a POST. If you're looking for the bytes received, you need to use mod_logio